# Quotient of graded ring is graded - confusion about the formalisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, graded-rings

A ring $R$ is graded if it has a direct sum decomposition $R=\bigoplus_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}R_i$ where the $R_i$ are abelian groups and $R_iR_j\subseteq R_{i+j}$. An ideal $I\subseteq R$ is graded if $I=\bigoplus_{i\in \mathbb{Z}}I_i$ where $I_i=R_i\cap I$. I want to prove that $R/I$ is a graded ring. Supposedly we do this by asserting that $R/I=\bigoplus_{i\in\mathbb{Z}} R_i/I_i$, and that $(R_i/I_i)(R_j/I_j)\subseteq R_{i+j}/I_{i+j}$ because $(r_i+I_i)(r_j+I_j)=r_ir_j+I_{i+j}$.

Here's where I am confused: how are the $R_i/I_i$ abelian subgroups of $R/I$? Seems like the best we could do is say they're isomorphic to subgroups of $R/I$. Furthermore, am I correct in saying that $(r_i+I_i)(r_j+I_j)=r_ir_j+I_{i+j}$ because that's how the multiplication in $\bigoplus_{i\in\mathbb{Z}} R_i/I_i$ is *defined*?

I feel like this graded quotient construction makes sense intuitively, but I'm getting caught up in these formalisms. Could anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: When an isomorphism is much too canonical, such as $R_i/I_i$ and its image in $R/I$, people often treat it as an equality.  But you are right to point out that the former is not a subset of the latter.

Comment: Technically, there's an isomorphism, but it's elided for the sake of brevity, which is typical in situations like this. This is the [internal vs. external](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Direct_sum#/Internal_and_external_direct_sums) direct sum distinction.

Answer (score 1):

(My English is not vert good)

Let S be a graded ring and I be its graded ideal.$S=S_0\oplus S_1\oplus\dots$

Let $S_k/I$ denote the set $\{x+I|x\in S_k \}$, Since $S_k$ is an abelian group,
$S_k/I$ is alse an abelian group.
Then we proof that $S/I = S_0/I\oplus S_1/I\oplus \dots$

It's easy to check that $S/I = S_0/I+  S_1/I+ \dots$ The uniqueness check as follow:
if $a_0+I+\dots+a_k+I=b_0+I+\dots+b_k+I$ then $a_0-b_0+\dots +a_k-b_k\in I=\oplus_{k=0}^{\infty}I\cap S_k$.
Hence, $a_0-b_0+\dots +a_k-b_k=c_1+\dots+c_m$,where $c_i\in S_i\cap I $.Finally we fill the "blank" with $0+I$ in left side and right side,we can get $a_i-b_i\in S_i\cap I$ by $S=S_0\oplus S_1\oplus\dots$.Then $a_i+I=b_i+I$,which indicates $S/I = S_0/I\oplus  S_1/I\oplus\dots$

$S_k/I\cong S_k/(I\cap S_k)$ is easy to check.